# Netbeans: jList index selection

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, indexing, jlist

Hi I am trying to make a popup window show when I click on an index of a jList. I am able to click on the items, but nothing happens. am I missing something? why isn't my jDialog opening?
My code looks like this:

```
private void jList3ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    

      jList3.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      jList3.addListSelectionListener((ListSelectionEvent le) -> {
          int idx = jList3.getSelectedIndex();
          if (idx != -1){
              jDialog5.setVisible(true);
              jDialog5.setSize(430, 555);
          }else{
              jDialog6.setVisible(true);
              jDialog6.setSize(430, 555);

          }
      });



}
```

Comment: how are you adding the listener to your JList?

Comment: By using this: import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener; but I can see that it is unused, do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Importing the listener is not enaugh. You need to add it to the list. Check [the official Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add the action listener to the component

```
 inx.addActionListener(this)
```